# SSIS_Get count of rows from source and load to destination

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, rowcount, ssis-2008

I have two OLEDB sources such as

```
 DB Source1= select count(*) from A
 DB Source2= select count(*) from B
```

Now, I need to get the count of Records uploaded

```
DB Source1 -DB Source2
```

for eg,

```
DBSource1 = 9 ;DBSource2=  1

then record uploaded will be 9-1=8
```

Finally I need them to be loaded to a flat file destination with following columns

```
RecordsReceived    ErrorRecords   RecordsUploaded
 9                    1                 8
```

How do I achieve this?
TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Row Count Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141136.aspx) task. This one will count your selected records that flow through it and store it in a variable you declared. You can use those variables later in your script to store them in a flat file.

Comment: Yes I tried that, used two row count transformations to store count of both values. then used Union All, then a derived column transformation to get DBsource1-DBsource2; then finally a flat file destination. I get 0 in all values